# Change caption of figure for references

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, naming

I changed the caption of my figures running the following command (I'm using the `babel` package):

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
```

If I use `\autoref{$LABEL}` to reference to the figure, however, it still shows the original figure caption, instead of "Abb. X".
Do I have to renew the command for `refname` as well? If so, would that change anything, if I now use `\ref` on something else besides my figures?

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}

\begin{document}

\autoref{fig:foobar}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \caption{BarFooCamp}
    \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `\autoref` macro of the `hyperref` package? If so, you may want to issue the command `\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Abb.}`.

Comment: I'm assuming that it uses the `\autoref` of `hyperref`, but inserting your code, doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. Please post an MWE (minimum working example) that shows what you've done so far in terms of trying to get the cross-reference to a `figure` environment be a associated with the `Abb.` prefix.

Comment: @Mico Just added a MWE, Gonzalo's answer, however, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the redefinition to `\extrasngerman`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Abb.}}

\begin{document}

\autoref{fig:test}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test caption}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]