# Figure to Fig in both Caption and Autoref

Tags: captions

I need to change the caption Figure to Fig. for a journal. I am currently using:

`\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}` and

```
%Caption display style
\captionsetup{figurename=Fig.,tablename=Table}
```

to rename the caption. The `\autoref` however, is still showing a `Figure 1` instead of `Fig. 1`. Can someone tell me the alternative to the code `\addto\extrasngerman{\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Abb.}}` used in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91471/change-caption-of-figure-for-references/159944#159944), applicable for `Caption` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this `\renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Fig.}`