# How to change Figure Label? (Fig.: n instead Figure: n)

Tags: floats, captions, package-options

This question seems to be asked a lot. I tried some different solutions and any of them did not work.

My figure caption is displayed as

```
Figure 1: Caption Here
```

But I want to display:

```
Fig. 1: Caption Here
```

I tried the instructions from several questions in the stackExchange website.

Currently my code looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf, figurename=Fig.]{caption} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
Drawing here
\caption{Caption here} \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the line \addto... the code does not compile.

I found these references in the following questions:

[Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

[Figure to Fig in both Caption and Autoref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159951/figure-to-fig-in-both-caption-and-autoref)

[How to change figure caption to Fig. 1. in stead of Fig. 1:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135482/how-to-change-figure-caption-to-fig-1-in-stead-of-fig-1)

none of them worked.

I also tried the solution the solution in this other link:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=3639
but no success.

I imagine that some of my packages might be in conflict with the caption one. But which one?

Any advice?

Comment: This is the classical case where *really* reducing the code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) should help. Just remove packages (there are some that are not needed for your example) until it works.

Comment: @zeh: you simply have to put the line `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}` *after* `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the linked post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Forget about `caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

Drawing here
\caption{Caption here}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here I just modified LaTeX command that shows in your captions. Now it displays as you want.

Comment: Sweet, work just great.
I added 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 
to have it in bold. 
However, what \makealetter and \makeatother do?

Comment: they switch on and off allowance for `@` in command sequences. Without those you cannot write commands with `@` inside. They are used only in cases like this one, where you want to modify something already written in `class` or `package` or `LaTeX`.

Comment: The question about what `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do is almost 7 years old, but there is a great answer to that question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/88529)

Comment: I think a nice improvement to this answer would explain what `\fnum@figure` is (where it is normally defined, how it is used, etc.)