# Insert a reference in a caption?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

After visiting [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) on labels and cross-referencing, a couple of tex sites ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91471/change-caption-of-figure-for-references),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31823/how-to-reference-subfigure-in-caption)), and a [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487728/latex-inserting-a-reference-in-a-figures-caption) solution, the following reference will not appear in the caption. I'm using pdflatex on ubuntu.

The section label that is being referenced (appen) is defined at the end of the doc. All of the following attempts to insert the reference in the caption produce **??** or [**?**]:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption*{See the ~\ref{appen} for language abbreviations.}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{{/filepath/hourly.update}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption*{See the ~\cite{appen} for language abbreviations.}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{{/filepath/hourly.update}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption*{See the ~\protect\ref{appen} for language abbreviations.}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{{/filepath/hourly.update}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption*{See the ~\protect\cite{appen} for language abbreviations.}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{{/filepath/hourly.update}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\section{Appendix}
\label{appen}
\subsection{Language Abbreviations}
 ...words, figures, tables, and such.
```

--
edit 2013-02-12

Error received:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `appen' on page 2 undefined on input line 94
```

Any idea how to insert a reference within a caption?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question does not share a relationship with the supposed duplicate. The error that I'm receiving is as follows: -- LaTeX Warning: Reference `appen' on page 2 undefined on input line 94

Comment: Did you read [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875) _completely_?

Comment: Yes. BibTeX is not the problem nor is that package being used. The problem is occurring with a reference within a caption. Your link is a great explaination for another problem dealing with bibliographies. As you can see both in my question and in the answer, I'm labeling a section so ~\cite{} is not useful. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one (using `\ref{appen}`) will give you, after *two* compilations, the expected result. The ones using `\cite` (which is to be used for bibliographical items) are incorrect. The one using `\protect\ref{appen}` will also yield the correct result, but `\protect` is not necessary. An example (notice that leaving a blank space before `~` will produce a superfluous space):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption*{See the Section~\ref{appen} for language abbreviations.}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{{/filepath/hourly.update}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\section{Appendix}
\label{appen}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The general mechanism for cross-referencing is to place

```
\label{<key>}
```

after an anchor has been generated (typically, after some automatic numbering has been done), and to use

```
\ref{<key>}
```

to cross-reference the labelled object.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: I really like that you warned about the `demo` option. I remember carrying over a lot of `lipsums` and similar example producing packages and options from answers on TeX.SX when I first started using the site.

Comment: @Gonzalo, those suggestions were tried and still produce the same error -- LaTeX Warning: Reference `appen' on page 2 undefined on input line 94. -- Let me know if you have any other ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @user28435 Did you try compiling my example code *exactly* as it is? What was the result after two compilations?